# How to make bold with array?

Tags: android, android-layout

I have a string array. i want to make bold with it. i try to . But it's not working. How can i make bold with array? please help me?

```
<string-array name="title_actionbars">
        <item >Trang chủ</item>
        <item>Thẻ game online</item>
        <item>Zing Card - Zing Xu - Vinagame</item>
        <item>Vcoin - VTC - Audition</item>
        <item>Thẻ Mobay - Minh Châu Corp</item>
        <item>Thẻ Bit - Qpal</item>
        <item>Oncash - VDC-Net2</item>
        <item>Gate - Bạc Gate - FPT</item>
        <item>Garena - Nạp Sò</item>
        <item>Thẻ Điện Thoại</item>
        <item>Thẻ Viettel</item>
        <item>Thẻ MobiFone</item>
        <item>Thẻ VinaPhone</item>
        <item>Lịch sử đơn hàng</item>
        <item >Thanh toán</item>
        <item>Giỏ hàng</item>
        <item>Đăng xuất</item>
        <item>Chi tiết thẻ</item>
    </string-array>
```

My java code. i add arraylist to drawerListMenu. But i want to change bold some item when i show arraylist to drawerListMenu. But is's working!

```
drawerListMenu.setOnItemClickListener(new SlideMenuClickListener());    
        // setting the nav drawer list adapter
        drawerListItemMenu = new ArrayList<DrawerItemMenu>();
        //add game menu
        drawerListItemMenu.add(new DrawerItemMenu(titleActionbars[0], iconMenus.getResourceId(4, -1), true));
        //add The dien thoai menu
        drawerListItemMenu.add(new DrawerItemMenu(titleActionbars[1], iconMenus.getResourceId(5, -1), true));
        //add history order menu        
        drawerListItemMenu.add(new DrawerItemMenu(titleActionbars[2], iconMenus.getResourceId(6, -1), true));
        //add The dien thoai menu
        drawerListItemMenu.add(new DrawerItemMenu(titleActionbars[3], iconMenus.getResourceId(6, -1), true));
        //add history order menu    
        drawerListItemMenu.add(new DrawerItemMenu(titleActionbars[4], iconMenus.getResourceId(6, -1), true));
        //add The dien thoai menu
        drawerListItemMenu.add(new DrawerItemMenu(titleActionbars[5], iconMenus.getResourceId(6, -1), true));
        //add history order menu        
        drawerListItemMenu.add(new DrawerItemMenu(titleActionbars[6], iconMenus.getResourceId(6, -1), true));
        //add The dien thoai menu
        drawerListItemMenu.add(new DrawerItemMenu(titleActionbars[7], iconMenus.getResourceId(6, -1), true));
        //add history order menu
        drawerListItemMenu.add(new DrawerItemMenu(titleActionbars[8], iconMenus.getResourceId(6, -1), true));
        //add The dien thoai menu
        drawerListItemMenu.add(new DrawerItemMenu(titleActionbars[9], iconMenus.getResourceId(5, -1), true));
        //add history order menu        
        drawerListItemMenu.add(new DrawerItemMenu(titleActionbars[10], iconMenus.getResourceId(6, -1), true));
        //add The dien thoai menu
        drawerListItemMenu.add(new DrawerItemMenu(titleActionbars[11], iconMenus.getResourceId(6, -1), true));
        //add history order menu
        drawerListItemMenu.add(new DrawerItemMenu(titleActionbars[12], iconMenus.getResourceId(6, -1), true));
        drawerListItemMenu.add(new DrawerItemMenu(titleActionbars[13], iconMenus.getResourceId(7, -1), true));
        //add logout menu when user info is saved on device
        drawerListItemMenu.add(new DrawerItemMenu(titleActionbars[16], iconMenus.getResourceId(2, -1), true)); //logout

        adapterMenu = new DrawerMenuAdapter(MainActivity.this, drawerListItemMenu);
        drawerListMenu.setAdapter(adapterMenu);
```

Comment: "But i want to change bold some item when i show arraylist to drawerListMenu"  Which items have to be bold? After what action do these items have to be bold? We aren't mind readers.

Comment: "But is's working!" Can you show what you have attempted for us to understand what you  are looking for?

Answer (score 0):

Strings.xml holds raw values of Strings and String-Array. Only the text when in a *View* can be made bold. The common views that can render string-arrays are TextView and Spinners.

```
<TextView 
     android:id="@+id/some_text_view" 
     android:textStyle="bold" />
<Spinner 
     android:id="@+id/some_spinner" 
     android:textStyle="bold" />
```

So now any value that you display in the TextView or Spinner will be bold. So now you have to assign the array properly to the appropriate view through your Java code.

Comment: I know about it. But it's not working for my string-array